# In java if "char c = 'a' " why does "c = c + 1" not compile?

Tags: java, casting, compiler-errors, char, primitive-types

I tried to compile the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    for (char c = 'a'; c <='z'; c = c + 1) {
        System.out.println(c);
    }
}
```

When I try to compile, it throws:

> Error:(5, 41) java: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from
>   int to char

The thing is, it does work if I write `c = (char)(c + 1)`, `c += 1` or `c++`.

I checked and the compiler throws a similar error when I try `char c = Character.MAX_VALUE + 1;` but I see no way that the value of 'c' can pass 'char' type maximum in the original function.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`c + 1` is an `int`, as the operands undergo [binary numeric promotion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2):

- `c` is a `char`
- `1` is an `int`

so `c` has to be widened to `int` to make it compatible for addition; and the result of the expression is of type `int`.

As for the things that "work":

- `c = (char)(c + 1)` is explicitly casting the expression to `char`, so its value is compatible with the variable's type;
- `c += 1` [is equivalent to](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2) `c = (char) ((c) + (1))`, so it's basically the same as the previous one.
- `c++` [is of type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.14.2) `char`, so no cast is required.

Comment: Good answer, only suggestion would be to mention _why_ you can set an int to a char, but not a char to an int (possible lossy conversion due to assigning a bigger data type to a smaller data type)

Comment: First of all, thank you for the good answer. Second, if I understand correctly, that mean java takes 'c + 1' and instead of casting '1' to a char it casts 'c' to an int in order to add them together. Is this because converting an int to char has a potential of losing data?

Comment: @רעיוייסליפשיץ yes. Note also that even if you add two chars together, they are still widened to int first. (Same is true of byte and short).

Comment: @רעיוייסליפשיץ "Note also that even if you add two chars together" so `c + (char) 1` wouldn't have worked.

Comment: Thanks, but that leaves me with a question, why does `char c = 97 + 1` work? wouldn't java see `97 + 1` as an int?

Comment: 97+1 is an int, but it is a compile-time constant, with value 98. Because the compiler can determine that this fits within the range of a char, it is automatically narrowed.

Comment: But c = 'a'+1 works fine !!

Comment: @ADITYADAS that's because `'a' + 1` is a compile-time constant expression, whose value can fit into a `char` without loss.

Answer (score -2):

First you are declaring c as char than you are using it as an int